# get number of used channels

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine (Python) and Chanel api. 
Is it possible to show how many chanels is available to users?
i wnat to show something like this: "Only %s places are available!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been requested and is currently an open issue:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655

EDIT:

You could easily track this on your own using a [sharded counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) that stores how many channels have been created so far for a given day and comparing that to the daily limit (100).